# GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I am receiving an error saying:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 404 (Not Found)
ng_zone.js:92Uncaught (in promise) Error: Angular requires Zone.js prolyfill.
    at new NgZone (ng_zone.js:92)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (application_ref.js:335)
    at application_ref.js:389
NgZone @ ng_zone.js:92
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone @ application_ref.js:335
(anonymous) @ application_ref.js:389
```

I have defined the zone.js fine in the **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drew's Demo Site</title>

    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>


    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->

</head>

<body>

    <my-app>Loading... </my-app>

</body>

</html>
```

I am sure what is going on. My IDE fills in the test as I type making me think the path is correct and I double check but it still gives a 404. I am wondering if there is a deeper issue.

Any advice would be appreciated.

GitHib Link: **NOTE** if you do pull the project add a directory assets to **src/assets**

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue.git)

Comment: Once I clone the github repo, how do I bring up the page. I mean how to build and deploy both back end and front end locally??

Comment: @pathrik Right now you don't really need the backend but if you want to set it up it is Spring-Boot, so just configure your IDE to the use the main method and java 8. For the frontend just cd into it from the terminal, and `npm start` after you do `npm install`. For some reason the assets `dir` didn't commit so just make it and place it under `src` and it will all work.

Comment: I  have no knowledge on angular 2, but one thing I seem to understand from initial look is that only files inside `src` folder will be served I guess. Since the js you are referring to is from outside `src` folder, it wont be available I guess. Will look more and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have created a pull request to your github with a fix. It might not be a correct fix but a working fix :)

https://github.com/drewjocham/AngularIssue/pull/1

The change I did basically was to move the zone.js import to angular-cli.json file.

Comment: I am also learning angular 2 rite now :). Can you let me know the sources that you used to create this App from? One I could see as using `ng init`. Any other  quick start kit or anything like that you used? Also, do you have the original app, that you said you had it under one Module? I can take that as a reference to learn :)